# Table is reset after I write it to PDF

Tags: java, swing, jtable, itext

I have a problem. After I click on my button, to add jTable to PDF and after saving it, the table disappears and when I clear it, the table gets bigger and destroys the UI. MainTable1 is the table that exists on my UI.

Here's the code:

```
    String path = "";
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table = mainTable1;
        JPanel tPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        tPanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(tPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
        PdfWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(500, 500);
            Graphics2D g2;
            g2 = tp.createGraphicsShapes(500, 500);
            table.print(g2);
            g2.dispose();
            cb.addTemplate(tp, 30, 300);
            document.close();
            tableToPDFButton.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HealthApplicationUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> and after saving it, the table disappears

```
    JTable table = mainTable1;
    JPanel tPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tPanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    tPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

A Swing component can only have a single parent. It looks to me like you are moving the table from one GUI to another.

If you want to copy the table then use the TableModel to create the second table:

```
JTable table = new JTable( mainTable1.getModel() );
```